# Pygame - Getting a bullet to fire up the screen on a MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event

Tags: python, oop, pygame

Creating a space invaders style game using sprites as a pose to images - Trying to get the bullet to continually move up the screen until it detects that it's passed y = 0. I've got an function to fire that moves the bullet up, but only by 5 pixels per MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event detected. Ideally, it needs to continue moving to the top of the screen after only one event is fired.

Here is the relevant code concerning the bullet class and the event loop.

```py
# bullet class

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,path):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(path)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def shoot(self,pixels):
        self.rect.y -= pixels

    def track(self):
        bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x + 23
```

And the event loop:

```py
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()  
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.moveLeft(5)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.moveRight(5)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullet.shoot(5)
    
    bullet.track()
  
    playerGroup.update()
    gameDisplay.blit(backgroundImg,(0,0))
    playerGroup.draw(gameDisplay)

    bulletGroup.update()
    bulletGroup.draw(gameDisplay)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Thanks to anyone who answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an additional attribute `shot` in your bullet class.  It
is initially set to `0` and updated when the `shoot` method is called.
Then the `track` method updates the `y` position of the bullet
accordingly.

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,path):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(path)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.shot = 0  #  bullet not shot initially

    def shoot(self, pixels):
        self.shot = pixels

    def track(self):
        self.rect.y -= self.shot
```

So, as soon as the button is clicked, the `shot` attribute is modified
and the bullet will keep moving.